# Functions in objective-c IOS

Tags: ios

I have an equation:

```
CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(20, 100);
CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(300, 100);
CGPoint controlPoint1 = CGPointMake(50, 250);
CGPoint controlPoint2 = CGPointMake(100, 250);

B(t) = (1-t)^3 * point1 + 3 * (1-t)^2 * t controlPoint1 + 3 * (1-t) * t^2 * controlPoint2 + t^3 * point2;
```

And I am trying to run it using an NStimer to get different values for B(t). I set 't' to be an integer (int t in my .h file). The problem is that I get the error:

"Implicit declaration of function B is invalid in C99"

If I do:

```
int h = (1-t)^3 * point1 + 3 * (1-t)^2 * t controlPoint1 + 3 * (1-t) * t^2 * controlPoint2 + t^3 * point2;
```

I get:

"Invalid operants to binary expression (int and CGPoint)".

and a pointer to the multiplication sign (*)

Comment: It's saying you can't mix int and CGPoint...you could do something like ...point1.x + 3... or something, but not the direct CGPoint variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is because B(t) looks like a function to the compiler, not a function in the mathematical sense. Storing the value in a variable like you've done will work, or you could write a function which accepts t and returns the current value.

The second error is because you are multiplying a scalar value (int) by a struct (CGPoint), you need to be multiplying by one of the points values (CGPoint consists of an x and y value), e.g. change `point1` to `point1.x` (disclaimer, i don't know this function so you'll have to work out which should be used)

Comment: I would also add that the carrot (^) symbol is not a power symbol in c++ or objective-c.  Use the pow() function instead.